# How to extract objects from SoftHSM with a JNA interface?

Tags: java, jna, pkcs#11, softhsm

I am using SoftHSM and I have to develop a Java application to extract objects of it.

I have a "Data" object of label "MY_DATA" and I have successfully opened the session on the right token.

But even if there is no error returned code, I cannot get anything: `objectHandles` is always empty (and `ulObjectCount` = 0).

Note that I get a list of handles when I use a null template. Thus, I think the issue is around the definition of the template (types used...) But what?

I am trying to get my Object with the following Java/JNA code (my JNA interface is called Pkcs11Library).

```java
String dataLabel = "MY_DATA";
CK_ATTRIBUTE[] searchTemplate = (CK_ATTRIBUTE[]) new CK_ATTRIBUTE().toArray(2);

searchTemplate[0].type = new NativeLong(Pkcs11Library.CKA_LABEL); // long CKA_LABEL = 0x00000003 
byte[] labelBytes = dataLabel.getBytes();
searchTemplate[0].pValue = new Memory(labelBytes.length);
searchTemplate[0].pValue.write(0, labelBytes, 0, labelBytes.length);
searchTemplate[0].ulValueLen = new NativeLong(labelBytes.length);

searchTemplate[1].type = new NativeLong(Pkcs11Library.CKA_CLASS); // long CKA_CLASS = 0x00000000
searchTemplate[1].pValue = new Memory(NativeLong.SIZE);
searchTemplate[1].pValue.setNativeLong(0, new NativeLong(Pkcs11Library.CKO_DATA)); // long CKO_DATA = 0x00000000
searchTemplate[1].ulValueLen = new NativeLong(NativeLong.SIZE);

int rv  = Pkcs11Library.INSTANCE.C_FindObjectsInit(hSession, searchTemplate, searchTemplate.length);
if (rv != Pkcs11Library.CKR_OK) {
  //TODO
}

int[] objectHandles = new int[MAX_OBJECT_COUNT]; // MAX_OBJECT_COUNT = 10
NativeLongByReference pulObjectCount = new NativeLongByReference();
rv = Pkcs11Library.INSTANCE.C_FindObjects(hSession, objectHandles, objectHandles.length, pulObjectCount);
int ulObjectCount = pulObjectCount.getValue().intValue();
```

My JNA interface is defined as follows:

```java
// CK_ATTRIBUTE
public class CK_ATTRIBUTE extends Structure {
  public NativeLong type;
  public Pointer pValue;
  public NativeLong ulValueLen;

  public CK_ATTRIBUTE() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("type", "pValue", "ulValueLen");
  }
}

int C_FindObjectsInit(int hSession, CK_ATTRIBUTE[] searchTemplate, int length);

int C_FindObjects(int hSession, int[] phObject, int ulMaxObjectCount, NativeLongByReference pulObjectCount);
```

The native definitions are [defined here](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2/blob/master/src/lib/SoftHSM.h):

```
struct ck_attribute
{
  ck_attribute_type_t type;
  void *value;
  unsigned long value_len;
};

CK_RV C_FindObjectsInit(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, CK_ATTRIBUTE_PTR pTemplate, CK_ULONG ulCount);
CK_RV C_FindObjects(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR phObject, CK_ULONG ulMaxObjectCount, CK_ULONG_PTR pulObjectCount);
```

I am on Windows x64 with OpenJDK17 and I use the x64 dll of SoftHSMv2.

Comment: What are the native headers of the structure and the function?  My brief searching shows `hSession` data type is eventually `CK_ULONG` which may have platform dependent mapping. It's the same type as your `Type` field in your structure which you've mapped as `NativeLong`.  One of those is wrong.

Comment: the native headers of SoftHSM pkcs11 implementation is here: [link](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2/blob/develop/src/lib/pkcs11/pkcs11.h) I think the issue is not around hsession because the way I use it works fine with a null template (`Pkcs11Library.INSTANCE.C_FindObjectsInit(hSession, null, 0);` allows to fill the list of objectsHandlers)

Comment: I am working on a Windows x64 with OpenJDK17 and I use the x64 dll of SoftHSMv2. I also tried to use simple 'int' type for the CK_ULONG fields, and also a byte[] for the pointer... nothing works

Comment: the code of C_FindObjectsInit is here: [link](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2/blob/develop/src/lib/SoftHSM.cpp); I think it goes well up to line 2011. Then, I don't know...

Comment: Then, if I try to go on with the list of objectHandlers and C_GetAttributeValue this way: `  CK_ATTRIBUTE[] template = (CK_ATTRIBUTE[]) new CK_ATTRIBUTE().toArray(1);<br/>
<br/>
  template[0].type = Pkcs11Library.CKA_LABEL; // or whatever the attribute type...<br/>
  template[0].pValue = null;<br/>
  template[0].ulValueLen = 0;<br/>
<br/>
        rv = Pkcs11Library.INSTANCE.C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, objectHandle, template, template.length);<br/>
` template[0].ulValueLen is always 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely [Data Structure Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86).  Third party libraries often don't use any alignment of bytes in structures.

Since your comments indicated you are on Windows, the various types that all map to `unsigned long` are 4 bytes each, so `int` is appropriate here. (I might suggest you be consistent in always using either `int` or `NativeLong`, it is confusing when you use both.)

However, pointer size is 8 bytes, so your structure byte width looks like:

```java
public NativeLong type; // 4 bytes
public Pointer pValue; // 8 bytes
public NativeLong ulValueLen; // 4 bytes
```

On Windows, JNA Structures use the default alignment to field width.  After assigning the first 4 bytes for `type`, it must assign the 8-byte value for `pValue`, but that must be 8-byte aligned.  The variable can't cross that byte boundary so therefore JNA is sending this structure:

```c
ffi_type_int32 type; // 4 bytes
ffi_type_int32 padding; // 4 bytes of padding to align pValue on 8-byte boundary
ffi_type_int64 pValue; // 8 bytes
ffi_type_int32 ulValueLen; // 4 bytes
```

To resolve this, use the [`setAlignType()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.13.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#setAlignType-int-) method using [`ALIGN_NONE`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.13.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#ALIGN_NONE) which doesn't use padding:

```java
@FieldOrder({ "type", "pValue", "ulValueLen" })
public class CK_ATTRIBUTE extends Structure {
    public int type;
    public Pointer pValue;
    public int ulValueLen;

    public CK_ATTRIBUTE() {
        super();
        setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
    }
}
```